# Business logic on FHIR

Tags: hapi-fhir, hl7-fhir

I want to implement some business logic rules on FHIR resources and I want to work with RESTFUL API methods.

An example: I've a `ServiceRequest` resource with a status, I want to prevent change of status depends of the actual value

Suppose if `ServiceRequest` has status `completed` I don't want to change with status `draft`

To manage this scenario, I must implement my custom method or exists a standard bahaviour on FHIR to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you'd implement this with a custom method.

Comment: So, in my case, is it correct use of DMI, pattern FHIR + SOA?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by DMI?

Comment: Sorrty, DMI was a fault copy paste. The right sentence is: So, in my case, is it correct use of pattern FHIR + SOA?

Comment: I think you'd need to describe your use case more :) but your question is correct, implementing a custom method to prevent the change of an element is OK. Make sure to document it in your Implementation Guide that changing that element isn't allowed.

Comment: Hi dear, I try to explain better my scenarios in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61951059/fhir-interoperability-platform-choose

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this answer and the Vadim answer is "apples and apples", but I think the term is *Operations*.

base resource:

https://www.hl7.org/fhir/servicerequest.html

then an operation off of that resource.

See

https://hapifhir.io/hapi-fhir/docs/server_plain/rest_operations_operations.html

http://hl7.org/fhir/operations.html

Here is a well known operation:

https://www.hl7.org/fhir/operation-patient-match.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.